# How to make a form that would send emails using only html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, email, contacts

Is there any way to make a form send an email using only html and javascript? As in, i want to create a form for my website that will allow someone to send me an email through that form, but i only want to use html + javascript for it.

Comment: you need your server with appropriate server side code, to actually send the email

Comment: You can set the To: field with mailto:myemail@example.com. Be aware that if the visitor doesn't have a web client installed then this will not work (think internet cafes and the like). Also be prepared for you inbox to be spammed out of existence as spambots look for these references to build their attack library.

Answer (score 0):

As @JaromandaX said, you needs a server to actually send the email.

JavaScript can only open the email window:

**Gmail:**

```
let customerEmail = '&to=' + email;
let emailSubject = "&su=" + markerName + ' - From yourService';
let emailBody = '&body=' + encodeURIComponent( ... );
window.open('https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&fs=1' + emailSubject + customerEmail + emailBody);
```

or **use `mailto`:**
More detail: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/Creating_hyperlinks

```
<a href="mailto:nowhere@mozilla.org">Send email to nowhere</a>
```